# Maven compiler plugin error

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have the following code in pom.xml for specifying the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
 <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2</version>
   <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Although the project compiles and runs OK, I have an error sign on my project root (I am using Eclipse).

If I comment out this excerpt, the error disappears, but of course, the project does not compile. I checked the [Maven website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/usage.html) but the specification is the same.

Could you please help me fixing this?

**Solution** (thanks to AleksandrM)

Changes in pom.xml cannot be applied to an eclipse project settings unless maven update project is called explicitly.

Click ALT + F5 on the project root and update maven project

Comment: Did you specify `jdk.version` in this pom or in its parent pom? Can you show us where this property is defined?

Comment: What is the error? Try `Alt` + `F5`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Alt + F5 and update Maven project, solved the error. But, what was the problem?

Comment: @STiGMa: Some changes in pom cannot be applied to eclipse project settings until the update project is called.

Comment: @STiGMa The problem was and is for ever this fcked up eclipse not able to handle I/O or its own state with the filesystem :)